# How can I store an image in a MySQL database using VB.NET?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How can I store an image in a MySQL database using VB.NET? Could you show some examples that use the `INSERT` command?

Answer (score 1):

Use the BLOB type.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,6172,15703

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of the Image data that you are saving, you'll want to use one of the flavors of the BLOB:

I think the max sizes on them are:

BLOB - 64KB max

MEDIUM BLOB - 16 MB max

LARGE BLOB - 4 GB max

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to store something like an image in a database is with a BLOB field (Binary Large Object), which is basically just a chunk of data.

Hope this is some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AccessImagine (http://access.bukrek.net), all you need to do is to bind it to some BLOB field in Properties Inspector.